# Count Rows On a Condition in SQL SERVER 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I want to fetch data in a following format from SQL SERVER 2000

```
Department | TotalPresent | Employee | Officer
XYZ              12           6          6
```

I am running this query

```
SELECT     a.department,
           Count(emp_id) AS totalpresent,
           CASE
                      WHEN a.type = 'Employee' THEN Count(a.type)
                      ELSE 0
           END AS employee,
           CASE
                      WHEN a.type = 'Officer' THEN Count(a.type)
                      ELSE 0
           END AS officer
FROM       attendancelog m
INNER JOIN employeedata a
ON         m.emp_id = a.emp_id groupby a.type,
           a.department
```

when i run this query i get this sort of data which is not correct

```
Department | TotalPresent | Employee | Officer
    XYZ              12           6         0
    XYZ              12           0         6
```

Please correct me what seems to be the problem why is it returning me the same records twice but fulfilling the condition

All i want to is count the rows on the condition whether the type is employee or officer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `type` from the `group by` and move the `case` inside the `sum()`:

```
Select a.department, count(emp_id) as TotalPresent,
       sum(case when a.Type = 'Employee' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Employee,
       sum(case when a.Type = 'Officer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Officer
from AttendanceLog m INNER JOIN
     EmployeeData a
     ON m.emp_id = a.emp_id
GroupBy a.Department;
```

Also, upgrade your SQL Server.  SQL Server 2000 has been *unsupported* for years.  You should try to use supported software.

Comment: thanx a ton, was making a silly mistake. Well we are upgrading from sql server 2000 it takes time few of the applications are dependent on it